# Getting Stringset from sharedpreferences from an other activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I can put the Stringset inside the SharedPreferences. But When I try to get the back I cant.

I am getting the set size  0

This is my code for saving  ====>

public class DefineProduct extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText productName, barcode,cost,price,size,color,notes;
Button saveBtn;
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor ;
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();


@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_define_product);

    sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    editor = sharedPref.edit();

    productName = findViewById(R.id.productNameText);
    barcode = findViewById(R.id.barcodeEditText);
    cost = findViewById(R.id.costText);
    price = findViewById(R.id.priceText);
    size = findViewById(R.id.sizeText);
    color = findViewById(R.id.colorText);
    notes = findViewById(R.id.notesText);
    saveBtn = findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);

}

public void Save(View view){

    set.add(productName.getText().toString());
    set.add(barcode.getText().toString());
    set.add(cost.getText().toString());
    set.add(price.getText().toString());
    set.add(size.getText().toString());
    set.add(color.getText().toString());
    set.add(notes.getText().toString());

    editor.putStringSet(barcode.getText().toString(),set);
    editor.commit();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    productName.setText("");
    barcode.setText("");
    cost.setText("");
    price.setText("");
    size.setText("");
    color.setText("");
    notes.setText("");
    set.clear();

}
```

}

This is my code for getting the StringSet from an other activity =====>

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data) {

    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);


    if(islem == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28){

                ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
                productImage = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
                productImageVeawer.setImageBitmap(productImage);
                productImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, byteArrayOutputStream);
            }

            else {
                productImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
                productImageVeawer.setImageBitmap(productImage);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if(islem == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        productImageVeawer.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, byteArrayOutputStream);

        }

    if(islem == 2){

        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        System.out.println("Scan result : " + result.getContents().toString());
        Set<String> set = pref.getStringSet(result.getContents().toString(), new HashSet<String>());
        System.out.println("***************************** Set size : " + set.size());

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.addAll(set);
```

//           barcodeText.setText(arrayList.get(0).toString());
 //           productNameText.setText(arrayList.get(1).toString());

```
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: This is my sharedpreferences  file     <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <set name="33333">
        <string>3</string>
        <string>Small</string>
        <string>33333</string>
        <string>Yellow</string>
        <string>6</string>
        <string>Üç</string>
        <string>Nörüyon</string>
    </set>
    <set name="86935241">
        <string>Sigara</string>
        <string>9</string>
        <string>86935241</string>
    </set>
</map>

Comment: do 'barcode.getText().toString()' and 'result.getContents().toString()' contain the exact same string?

Comment: yes. they are exactly same

Comment: it seems like you put an emtpy hashset into sharedpref.

Comment: check below code

Comment: Just Stetho(https://github.com/facebook/stetho) and check if its saving in preference or not and with proper key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor ;
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_define_product);

    sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    editor = sharedPref.edit();

}

public void Save(View view){
    editor.putStringSet(barcode.getText().toString(),set);
    editor.apply();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    set.clear();
}
```

and to fetch data in another activity

```
public NameActivity extands AppCompactActivity{
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor ;

@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_define_product);

    sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    Set<String> fetch = sharePref.getStringSet(barcode.getText().toString(), null);
     }
}
```

Comment: My sharedpref is not empty. I am trying to get the values from another activity.

Comment: check updated answer and  tell me is it working or not

Comment: now my set is null     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.Set.size()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.istakip.AddProduct.onActivityResult(AddProduct.java:206)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7762)

Comment: and replace this line  Set<String> set = pref.getStringSet(result.getContents().toString(), new HashSet<String>());

Comment: with this  Set<String> set = pref.getStringSet(result.getContents().toString(),null);

Comment: I am still getting null

Comment: and do one thing i.e. replace this   editor.putStringSet("barcode"
,set); while saving data in sharepreference and while retriving use this  Set<String> set = pref.getStringSet("barcode", null); and tell me the output

Comment: Its working now.  But values are not being added in proper order now.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting empty Set to preference, you should add some value to the Set and save like following

```
set.add("Test"); 
editor.putStringSet(barcode.getText().toString(),set);
editor.apply(); // must apply the change
```

Comment: No Its not empty. I didnt paste all code. I am putting the below data                                                    set.add(productName.getText().toString());
        set.add(barcode.getText().toString());
        set.add(cost.getText().toString());
        set.add(price.getText().toString());
        set.add(size.getText().toString());

Comment: I putted all my code. I am trying to get the sharedpref from an other activity

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the PreferenceManager, use

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext.getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
```

To keep the filename easy to remember, I use the package name. Also, make sure you use "" around the filename.